# What are some effective strategies for handling mutually exclusive properties in React with Typescript, with an aim to improve developer experience?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, autocomplete, react-tsx, mutual-exclusion

I'm currently working on a **React** project using **TypeScript** and am encountering an issue regarding the management of **mutually exclusive props**.
My aim is to find a **more effective strategy** to handle these, with a focus on improving the overall developer experience. I'm aware that handling mutually exclusive properties can sometimes be tricky and can introduce additional complexity into the codebase. Therefore, I am looking for ways to make this **process more streamlined** and less prone to errors and complexity.

Let's suppose i have `MyComponent` like this:

```
interface CommonProps {
    commonProp1: string;
    commonProp2: string;
    commonProp3: string;
}

interface Component1Props extends CommonProps {
    component1Prop1?: string;
    component1Prop2?: string;
    component1Prop3?: string;
    component2Prop1?: never;
    component2Prop2?: never;
    component2Prop3?: never;
    
}

interface Component2Props extends CommonProps {
    component2Prop1?: string;
    component2Prop2?: string;
    component2Prop3?: string;
    component1Prop1?: never;
    component1Prop2?: never;
    component1Prop3?: never;
}

type ComponentProps = Component1Props | Component2Props;

const MyComponent: FC<ComponentProps> = ...
```

In the above code, it seems complex to me, and I'm not a fan of having every prop suggested by TypeScript's autocomplete feature. For instance, if I declare component1Prop1, I don't want to see the ones put to never ( but this is another topic, since we have to list every props in the FC)

Now, I've been **considering a different approach**, but I'm not sure if it can be feasibly implemented:

```
interface Props {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
    prop3: string;
    prop4: string & Red;
    prop5: string & Red;
    prop6: string & Red;
    prop7: string & Blue;
    prop8: string & Blue;
    prop9: string & Blue;
    prop10: string & Orange;
    prop11: string & Orange;

}


const MyComponent: TFC<Props> = ({
    disable: {
        Red: { Blue, Orange}
    },
    allow: {
        Red : { Orange['prop11'] }
    }
})
...
```

EDIT: more information about my intent: a compile-time mechanism to enforce mutually exclusive properties within the React props based on custom types like Red and Blue.

```
interface MyProps {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
    prop3: string;
    prop4?: string & Red;
    prop5?: string & Red;
    prop6?: string & Red;
    prop7?: string & Blue;
    prop8?: string & Blue;
    prop9?: string & Blue;
}

type Red = { __red: true };
type Blue = { __blue: true };

type PropSet<N, T> = { [P in keyof N]: N[P] extends T ? never :  N[P] };

type Disabled<P> = {
    [K in keyof P]: P[K] extends Red ? PropSet<P, Blue> : P[K] extends Blue ? PropSet<P, Red> : P[K];
}


const MyComponent = (props: Disabled<MyProps>) => {
    return <div>MyComponent</div>
}

export default MyComponent;
```

However i dont get errors when i create the component and the two props are from different colors:

```
 <MyComponent prop1="none" prop2="none" prop3="none" prop4="red" prop8="blue"/> // no error
```

The key concept involves **disabling certain properties marked with a tag (which could be anything not just colors ), and allowing exceptions in certain cases in a very easy way.** This could potentially reduce the risk of incorrect property assignment and enhance autocompletion features even for the most unexperied devs.

What are your thoughts on this approach? Can it be feasibly implemented? Are there other strategies or best practices that you have used to handle mutually exclusive properties that improved your developer experience? I look forward to hearing your insights and recommendations.

Comment: Please provide `Red`, `Orange`, `Blue`

Comment: Also, there are no `disable`, `allow` props in your `Props`. Not sure what you are trying to achieve with that

Comment: Please provide some test cases, it's really hard to understand the end result

Comment: Sorry, it wasn’t an actual implementation, it was a sort of pseudo code. The Red, Blue, Color  type are just tag. The aim is to abstract the entire process of mutual exclusion customising the FC component to make the process easier. However I will provide some test cases asap.

Comment: That would be really helpful and I'm not sure what do you mean by `tag`

Comment: Hello @wonderflame hope i had clarified my intent, thank you for your time

Comment: will take a look in couple of hours

Comment: I'm still not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mLvQAw) work for you? If, yes I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Did it work for you?